# Error when loading Heroku app

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku

Error when trying to open Heroku app (Ruby)

Ran, run console and this is what I got back. Can someone help me with correcting these errors.

> Running rails console on jay-bro-app... up, run.7773
>   /app/vendor/ruby-2.0.0/lib/ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/dependency.rb:296:in
>   `to_specs': Could not find 'spring' (= 1.4.3) among 61 total gem(s)
>   (Gem::LoadError)  from
>   /app/vendor/ruby-2.0.0/lib/ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/dependency.rb:307:in`
>   to_spec'     from
>   /app/vendor/ruby-2.0.0/lib/ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_gem.rb:47:in
>   `gem'     from /app/bin/spring:12:in`'   from
>   /app/bin/rails:4:in `load'    from /app/bin/rails:4:in`'

Comment: Can you post your gem file¿

Answer (score 0):

As I know, 'spring' only is being used for development/test env. So make sure you are defining like this in your Gemfile

```
gem "spring", group: :development
```

For detail pls check [here](https://github.com/rails/spring). This is one note from previous link:

> You must not install Spring on your production environment. To prevent it from being installed, provide the --without development test argument to the bundle install command which is used to install gems on your production machines:
>
> bundle install --without development test

Then just rerun

```
heroku run bundle install
```

And restart server, hope it works for you